# Flutter Re-run cmake with a different source directory

Tags: flutter, cmake, runtime-error

When I tried to run Flutter app on windows, it gives an error then says Exited Sigterm. or stmh like this.

the error says; 
Re-run cmake with a different source directory 
cmake files does not match... 
etc.

Comment: It is better to include **exact** error message into the question post, not just some words  of that message.

Comment: Sorry about that, I shared this after I solved the problem, so I wasn't have the error codes :(

Answer (score 4):

The Steps that helped me to handle this error are;

1. open your terminal then write following commands
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. flutter run

This will remove you build file and re-create it.
Your problem should have solved now.